# no result with multiple table query in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get result from two tables with following query in php:

```
r2 = $con->query('
  (
   SELECT * 
   FROM pat 
   WHERE pfn LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" 
     OR pfln LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
  ) UNION all (
   SELECT * 
   FROM patfam 
   WHERE fn LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" 
     OR ln LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"
  )'
);
```

But there no result set in $r2, it returns FALSE.

I can get result with two select statements but with union I am getting false

so am I missing something here ?

thanks

Comment: Find out what the error message is. Use either `$con->errorInfo()` (PDO) or `$con->error` (mysqli).

Comment: Allways allways allways get yourself an error message! Solves 99% of all StackOverflow questions instantly and without help.

Comment: Show us your tables' schemas. Are the columns identical (for `UNION` to work properly)?

Comment: thanks for your inputs, I have got this error: 'The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns'. So columns are not identical. So how can I get results from both table with single query ?

Comment: 1 way is to name the columns you're selecting in both tables and fill the empty ones if one table has more columns than the other... example: SELECT id as id, name as name, column3 as column3 from table1 union `SELECT id_table2 as id, fname as name, '' as column3 from table2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 way is to name the columns you're selecting in both tables and fill the empty ones if one table has more columns than the other... example:

```
SELECT id AS id, name AS name, column3 AS column3, 'table1' as table_name FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT id_table2 AS id, fname AS name, '' AS column3, 'table2' as table_name FROM table2
```

Comment: one more related question: how can I distinguish results based on which table they came ?

Comment: @BhavinToliya, updated my answer, you can add 1 column that you fill it automatically and name it the same in both tables this way you can distinguish where did every row come from.